# Android : Error Inflating Fragment Class

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-fragments

I have an app which uses the default Android Master/Detail Flow, but when I try to compile it, I get the following error, here is the stack trace:

```
01-25 23:07:09.557    1391-1391/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.HarrisMirzaApps.weatherapp, PID: 1391
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.HarrisMirzaApps.weatherapp/com.HarrisMirzaApps.weatherapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.HarrisMirzaApps.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
            at com.HarrisMirzaApps.weatherapp.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:88)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.HarrisMirzaApps.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have looked at many similar posts, but the solutions didn't work for me.

More Info

Line 27 is the start of the Fragment tag for the navigation drawer in activity_main.xml:

```
NavigationDrawerFragment.Java:88 is the following :
mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
```

Thanks In Advance,
Harris Mirza

Comment: It's easier to answer your question if you provide us with both your activity_main.xml and NavigationDrawerFragment.class. And / or other classes that may be the source of your problem. It looks like it's some problem in the fragment layout xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based solely on the snippet you posted it appears that the problem is in your ids

> mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

Is `R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer` a layout file? if so, you can't cast it to a ListView, even if there is only a ListView in the layout file.

you will need to inflate the layout into a View, then findByViewId the included ListView

Comment: Actually, he/she can cast a layout to a ListView, but ONLY if it is a ListView. In his/her case (according to the stacktrace) he/she is trying to cast a LinearLayout to al Listview.

Comment: Thanks, i added a LinearLayout to the fragment_navigation_drawer, i should have worked that out myself!